# adobe flash cs3 error 1119: ball.vx is showing as undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

here is my code to make multiple spring animation. but I am getting this error. 
ball.vx and ball.vy are showing as undefined property.

I tried this code from Keith Peters' "Foundation
ActionScript 3.0 Animation
Making Things Move!"

does anyone know how to fix it?

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
public class Chain extends Sprite
{
private var ball0:Ball;
private var ball1:Ball;
private var ball2:Ball;
private var vx:Number = 0;
private var vy:Number = 0;
private var spring:Number = 0.1;
private var friction:Number = 0.8;
private var gravity:Number = 5;

public function Chain()
{
init();
}
private function init():void
{
ball0 = new Ball(20);
addChild(ball0);
ball1 = new Ball(20);
addChild(ball1);
ball2 = new Ball(20);
addChild(ball2);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
}
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
moveBall(ball0, mouseX, mouseY);
moveBall(ball1, ball0.x, ball0.y);
moveBall(ball2, ball1.x, ball1.y);
graphics.clear();
graphics.lineStyle(1);
graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
graphics.lineTo(ball0.x, ball0.y);
graphics.lineTo(ball1.x, ball1.y);
graphics.lineTo(ball2.x, ball2.y);
}
private function moveBall(ball:Ball,
targetX:Number,
targetY:Number):void
{
ball.vx += (targetX - ball.x) * spring;
ball.vy += (targetY - ball.y) * spring;
ball.vy += gravity;
ball.vx *= friction;
ball.vy *= friction;
ball.x += ball.vx;
ball.y += ball.vy;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you faced this problem:

[Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Animation Making Things Move!](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/885/) source code each folder have a `Ball.as` some different. ch03, ch05 `Ball.as` not have a property `vx`,`vy`. you should import ch06 or upper folder `Ball.as` they have a `vx`,`vy` as follows:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Ball extends Sprite {
        public var radius:Number;
        private var color:uint;
        public var vx:Number = 0;
        public var vy:Number = 0;

        public function Ball(radius:Number=40, color:uint=0xff0000) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.color = color;
            init();
        }
        public function init():void {
            graphics.beginFill(color);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: many many thanks for your little but valuable support. I was wasting time but coudnt find out what the problem is. on the other hand, I couldnt go ahead leaving this. best wishes. :) (bruce)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us Ball class? Probably vx and vx aren't declared.

Comment: I was using ball.as from chapter which didnt include vx and vy properties. Now I got the solution. thanks for your support.